# Failed to get dynamic instance variables via PHP's reflection

Tags: php, reflection

I failed to get dynamic instance variables via PHP's reflection

Sample code:

```
<?php

class Foo
{
    public function bar()
    {         
        $reflect = new ReflectionClass($this);
        $props   = $reflect->getProperties();
        var_export($props);
        die;
    }
}

$foo = new Foo();
$foo->a = "a";
$foo->b = "b";

$foo->bar(); // Failed to print out variable a and b
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`ReflectionClass::getProperties()` gets only properties *explicitly defined* by a class. To reflect all properties you set on an object, use [`ReflectionObject`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionobject.php) which inherits from `ReflectionClass` and works on runtime instances:

```
$reflect = new ReflectionObject($this);
```

Or as [Tim Cooper says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4914376/failed-to-get-dynamic-instance-variables-via-phps-reflection/4914404#4914404), forget reflection and just use [`get_object_vars()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php) instead.

Comment: As a note, we discovered that in certain versions of PHP 7.0.* run via PHP-FPM (confirmed present in PHP 7.0.10, believed fixed as of 7.0.17, but certainly as of 7.0.20), `get_object_vars()` does not return any dynamically added object/class attributes, only public properties explicitly defined by a class. This is an undocumented change in behavior from earlier and later versions of PHP. In cases where it is not possible/practical to upgrade a server in the short-term, the `ReflectionObject` framework provides a workable solution to the temporarily broken functionality of `get_object_vars()`.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot use `ReflectionClass` in this situation. Replace your `$props` variable with the following to make it work:

```
$props = get_object_vars($this);
```

If there is no other method you need to call from `ReflectionObject` (see [BoltClock's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4914376/failed-to-get-dynamic-instance-variables-via-phps-reflection/4914405#4914405)), then this is the simplest solution.

Comment: @BoltClock times goes fast huh

Answer (score 1):

```
class Foo { }
$foo = new Foo();
$foo->a = "a";
$foo->b = "b";
echo Reflection::export(new ReflectionObject($foo));

// Object of class [ <user> class Foo ] {
//   @@ /var/www/files/r.php 2-2
//   - Constants [0] {
//   }
//   - Static properties [0] {
//   }
//   - Static methods [0] {
//   }
//   - Properties [0] {
//   }
//   - Dynamic properties [2] {
//     Property [ <dynamic> public $a ]
//     Property [ <dynamic> public $b ]
//   }
//   - Methods [0] {
//   }
// }
```

Answer (score 0):

## A detailed explanation on both answeres above

Given the instance of an anonymous class

```php
$object             = new class()
{
    private $fooPrivate = 'barPrivate';

    public $fooPublic = 'barPublic';

    public static $fooStaticPublic = 'barStaticPublic';

    public function getProperties(): array
    {
        return get_object_vars( $this );
    }
};

$object->fooDynamic = 'barDynamic';
```

---

### Getting the properties by reflection

#### with `ReflectionClass`

```php
/** lists: `fooPrivate`, `fooPublic`, `fooStaticPublic` */
var_export(
    ( new ReflectionClass( $object ) )
        ->getProperties()
);

/** lists: `fooPublic`, `fooStaticPublic` */
var_export(
    ( new ReflectionClass( $object ) )
        ->getProperties( ReflectionProperty::IS_PUBLIC )
);
```

#### with `ReflectionObject`

```php
/** lists: `fooPrivate`, `fooPublic`, `fooStaticPublic`, `fooDynamic` */
var_export(
    ( new ReflectionObject( $object ) )
        ->getProperties()
);

/** lists: `fooPublic`, `fooStaticPublic`, `fooDynamic` */
var_export(
    ( new ReflectionObject( $object ) )
        ->getProperties( ReflectionProperty::IS_PUBLIC )
);
```

---

### Getting the properties by `get_object_vars()`

```php
/** lists: `fooPublic`, `fooDynamic` */
var_export(
    get_object_vars( $object )
);

/** lists: `fooPrivate`, `fooPublic`, `fooDynamic` */
var_export(
    $object->getProperties()
);
```

---

### Summary

- `ReflectionClass::getProperties()`

  - cannot fetch dynamically assigned properties
- `ReflectionObject::getProperties()`

  - can fetch dynamically assigned properties
- `ReflectionClass::getProperties()` and `ReflectionObject::getProperties()` both

  - can fetch static properties
  - can fetch properties no matter their defined access scope
  - both can be called with a filter
- `get_object_vars()`

  - can fetch dynamically assigned properties
  - cannot fetch static properties
  - cannot fetch properties the calling scope does not have access to, which is absolutely correct in the way access modification is meant to work in OOP